# calculate the cumulative sum in an array from conditions

Tags: sum, cumulative-sum, cumsum

in another language I use there is a function called SumSince( condition, array ). So for instance I have a DataArray and a ConditionArray that look like

| DataArray | ConditionArray | ResultArray |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | 6 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 0 | 9 |
| 6 | 0 | 15 |

then ResultArray = SumSince( ConditionArray, DataArray ) would give the array shown in the 3-rd column

So it starts cumulation from the condition. When a new condition it met it will start cumulating from scratch from that condition.

Is there such a similar function in Python somewhere. I couldn't find it. I know I could use a loop but I am pretty sure there is a function somewhere that enables to to this

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i just wrote my own function for the time being. In Pandas you have Cumsum. I just did not find how to use it as SumSince. I wrote a function below. Seems to work. Probably ugly code but just beginning using Python. If someone knows an already existing functionality for this please let me know, thanks

```
def SumSince(condition, array):
    length = len(array)
    outputArray = [0] * length
    i = 0
    csum = 0
    while i < length:
        if (condition[i] == 0):
            csum = array[i] + csum
            outputArray[i] = csum
        elif (condition[i] == 1):
            csum = array[i]
            outputArray[i] = csum
        i += 1
    return outputArray
```

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
condition = [1,0,0,1,0,0]
tst = SumSince(condition, array)

tst
[1, 3, 6, 4, 9, 15]
```

Comment: I actually solved it differently. The result is the same but this works faster. I work with "tick data" files where each day is stored in a file. These files are processed to minute files where I want to sum up information each minute. So now I make sure each minute per day has its own number and the I use groupby:        df['hourplusminute'] = df.index.hour * 60 + df.index.minute
                df['cum_volume_at_ask'] = df['volume_at_ask'].groupby(df['hourplusminute']).cumsum()
                df['cum_volume_at_bid'] = df['volume_at_bid'].groupby(df['hourplusminute']).cumsum()